# Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object in Enterprise portal in Dynamics AX

Tags: assemblies, microsoft-dynamics, ax, enterprise-portal

I am getting following error in enterprise portal in Dynamics AX

```
Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.

Microsoft.Dynamics.Framework.Portal

   at Microsoft.Dynamics.Framework.Portal.UI.WebControls.AxFilter.GetFilterStringFromPostBackValue(String postBackValue)
   at Microsoft.Dynamics.Framework.Portal.UI.WebControls.AxFilter.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
```

Comment: Please consider adding more information. What are you trying to do. When it occurs, and any other relevant information to solve the problem (OS...).

Comment: I am trying to access run export to excel button command in Enterprise portal. Also, when I try to click on any record on list page on the same page, this error is displayed

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that the error appears in the modal windows. You can try to set the property `<dynamics:AxGridView ShowFilter="false"/>` and error disappears

Comment: This is not modal window. This is export to excel button in action pane of listpage. The list page is the same as in AX client. Also, this error appears when any record on the grid of list page is clicked

Comment: I have checked other operations like changing company, editing page on the same list page as well. It's throwing the same error.This is the list page which is created in enterprise portal by deploying existing list page present in Client. Any idea how to resolve it?

Comment: Finally, I got the solution. I had kept the query status as locked after applying filter to datasource in initialize query method of interaction class. I removed the code and it worked.. Thanks